# How to force Windows 8 to re-read CD/DVD drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, optical-drive

Only once in a blue moon have i ever seen this before Windows 8, but now it is a constant problem. When changing media in my CD/DVD drive (SAMSUNG SH-S203N) whatever was previously in the drive is still displayed. For instance, removing an audio CD and putting in a DVD with an application i wish to install, it still displays in Windows Explorer as an audio CD. I can usually manage to get it to display as empty. And then, eventually, the actual contents will display. This can involve many ejects and re-reads, or waiting 20 minutes, or whatever, but it is becoming a serious annoyance.

Surely there's a setting that's controlling how often Windows 8 rereads the drive vs. reading its cached idea about the drive. I want it to dump the cache and re-read the drive as soon as i load a new disc. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you actually browse the contents of the new CD?

Comment: That's what i'm saying; it is not recognized as having anything other than the previous content. So audio track 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: I'm wondering what happens if you try and actually access the data. Maybe that will force windows to refresh. Perhaps attempting to play the audio CD?

Comment: I've seen this before, but turned out the drive was broken. Replacing it fixed the issue.